# Xamarin Forms - capturing photo from camera (Android)

Tags: forms, xamarin, camera, capture

A callback for the camera never gets invoked when I take a photo. It only gets invoked when I select existing photo from a gallery.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<byte[]>(this, "ImageSelected", (args) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
        //Set the source of the image view with the byte array   <<== NEVER INVOKED 
        Image img = new Image();

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((byte[])args);

        //img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream((byte[])args));

        imagePallet.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream; });

        imagePreview.IsVisible = true;

        });
    });
```

I am using the setup outlined here: 
https://baglabs.com/2017/01/12/xamarin-forms-using-camera-photo-gallery/

I noticed the OnActivityResult executes in MainActivity.cs but the Data property of Intent is always null when select photo taken from camera, it's only set when selecting photo from gallery as before.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //Since we set the request code to 1 for both the camera and photo gallery, that's what we need to check for
    if (requestCode == 1)
    {
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            if (data.Data != null)  --<<==ALWAYS NULL WHEN ACCEPTING PHOTO TAKEN WITH CAMERA
            {
                //Grab the Uri which is holding the path to the image
                Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;

                //Read the meta data of the image to determine what orientation the image should be in
                int orientation = getOrientation(uri);

                //Stat a background task so we can do all the bitmap stuff off the UI thread
                BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(this.ContentResolver, uri);
                task.Execute(orientation);
            }


        }
    }
```

Clearly I am missing something. Many thanks!

Comment: How do you build/create the intent of taking a picture?